# dart pub not setting symlinks to local package

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
- /dart_demo
  - main.dart
  - pubspec.yaml
- /core
  - core.dart
  - pubspec.yaml
```

dart_demo is my entry point app, its pubspec looks like this:

```
name: dart_demo
dependencies:
  core:
    path: ../core/
```

the core library's pubspec is this:

```
name: core
version: 0.0.1
description: >
  My core library.
dependencies:
  xml: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"
  browser: ">=0.10.0+2 <0.11.0"
```

when i run pub get inside dart_demo, it creates a packages folder with the dependencies needed by my core package, such as xml. but my own core package is not symlinked in my dart_demo packages folder.

how can i get the references to my core classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is the basic cause of the problem but to be able to import a package the package must have something inside its `lib` directory.

You should move your `main.dart` into the subfolder `bin` of your `dart_demo` package if it is a command line application or `web` if its code for a web page.

You should move your `core.dart` file into the subfolder `lib` of your `core` package.

If it still doesn't work pleas add a comment.